# change bool value mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

m beginner at react i have a little problem i want to change a bool value which is isApproved so the admin click a button and approve the post so it can be displayed here is my code . can anyone help me

this is the function that change the value of isApproved

```
//@route put api/posts/approve/:id
//@desc approve post
//@access Private

router.post('/:id/approve', auth, async(req, res) => {
    console.log("action base de donne begin");
    Post.findById(req.params.id, (err, post) => {
        console.log(post.isApproved);
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else if (post.isApproved == false) {
            post.update({$set: {isApproved: true}});
            
        } else {
            post.update({$set: {isApproved: false}});
            
        }
    });
});
```

the post model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String
  },
  isApproved: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  likes: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
      }
    }
  ],
  comments: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
      },
      text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      name: {
        type: String
      },
      avatar: {
        type: String
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      }
    }
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Post = mongoose.model('post', PostSchema);
```

approve action :

```
// Approve Approve 


export const approve = id => async dispatch => {
  
  
  try {
    console.log('action is begin');
    console.log(id);
    const res = await axios.post(`/api/posts/${id}/approve`);
    console.log('la valeur dans action est',res)
    dispatch({
      type: APPROVE_POST,
      payload: { id, isApproved: res.data }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

post reducers

```
import {
  GET_POSTS,
  POST_ERROR,
  UPDATE_LIKES,
  DELETE_POST,
  ADD_POST,
  GET_POST,
  ADD_COMMENT,
  REMOVE_COMMENT,
  APPROVE_POST
} from '../actions/types';



const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  post: null,
  loading: true,
  error: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case GET_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case ADD_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: [payload, ...state.posts],
        loading: false
      };
    case DELETE_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.filter(post => post._id !== payload),
        loading: false
      };
    case POST_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case UPDATE_LIKES:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.map(post =>
          post._id === payload.id ? { ...post, likes: payload.likes } : post
        ),
        loading: false
      };
      case APPROVE_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.map(post =>
          post._id === payload.id ? { ...post, isApproved: payload.isApproved } : post
        ),
        loading: false
      };
    case ADD_COMMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: { ...state.post, comments: payload },
        loading: false
      };
    case REMOVE_COMMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        post: {
          ...state.post,
          comments: state.post.comments.filter(
            comment => comment._id !== payload
          )
        },
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

```
 case APPROVE_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: state.posts.map(post =>
          post._id === payload.id ? { ...post, isApproved: payload.isApproved } : post
        ),
        loading: false
      };
```

Comment: It would help if you used punctuation and broke your question text into actual sentences, rather than just strings of words. Frankly, I feel zero motivation to spent time trying to help someone who doesn't show an effort in making it easy to understand the problem they are asking for help with.

Answer (score 0):

`{ "$eq": [ false, "$isApproved" ] }` will return true or false

```
db.collection.update(
  {},
  [  { "$set": { "isApproved": { "$eq": [ false, "$isApproved" ] } } } ]
);
```

Use [findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/4kCEaEpuIko

Answer (score 0):

i change the code to this but i always have a false value

```
router.post('/:id/approve', auth, async(req, res) => {
    console.log("action base de donne begin");
    Post.findById(req.params.id, (err, post) => {
        console.log(post.isApproved);
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else if (post.isApproved == false) {
            post.update(
                {},
                [  { "$set": { "isApproved": { "$eq": [ true, "$isApproved" ] } } } ]
              );
            
        } else {
            post.update(
                {},
                [  { "$set": { "isApproved": { "$eq": [ false, "$isApproved" ] } } } ]
              );
            
        }
    });
});
```